# why my code error,I would like to print the parameters of two functions

Tags: python

```
def c(*x,**y):
    print x,y
def a(*x,**y):
    print x
    def b(*x1,**y1):
        c(*(x+x1),**dict(y,**y1))
    b()

a(1,2,3,a=1,b=2)(4,5,6,c='222',d='aaa')#error
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Exactly what error message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace b() with return b

Running this in Python 3.1:

```
def c(*x,**y):
    print(x,y)
def a(*x,**y):
    print(x)
    def b(*x1,**y1):
        c(*(x+x1),**dict(y,**y1))
    return b

a(1,2,3,a=1,b=2)(4,5,6,c='222',d='aaa')
```

produces:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) {'a': 1, 'c': '222', 'b': 2, 'd': 'aaa'}
>>>
```

Comment: Yeah, Python doesn't automatically return the last line of the function.

Comment: And even if it did, returning b() wouldn't work because that would return the return value of b (None).

Answer (score 2):

function a() is not returning a function; actually, it returns `None`. Therefore, the second set of parenthesis is a call on None object - and that's an error.
Did you intend to return a function, like doing something like `return b`?

Answer (score 1):

```
a(1,2,3,a=1,b=2)(4,5,6,c='222',d='aaa')#error
```

I assume you got "object is not callable" exception..

May be you need to return a function object 'b' (not result of the 'b') ?

So instead of

```
b()
```

try

```
return b # without braces and with 'return'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./tmp.py", line 11, in 
>       a(1,2,3,a=1,b=2)(4,5,6,c='222',d='aaa')
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not
>   callable

I can fix this by changing your code to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def c(*x,**y):
    print x,y
def a(*x,**y):
    print x
    def b(*x1,**y1):
        c(*(x+x1),**dict(y,**y1))
    return b

a(1,2,3,a=1,b=2)(4,5,6,c='222',d='aaa')
```

This produces the output:

> (1, 2, 3)
>
> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) {'a': 1,
>   'c': '222', 'b': 2, 'd': 'aaa'}

You haven't stated what you're trying to achieve though, so I don't know whether or not this is what you want.